# CDI Beans and Hibernate Envers

Tags: cdi, hibernate-envers

I'm beggining with Hibernate Envers. I'm already able to properly annotate classes with @Audited and create revisions, but I'm unable to record logged user data with my revisions.

My JSF 2.0 test application is running on CDI, JPA/Hibernate in a jbossEAP6 / wildfly server. I'm neither using Spring or Seam.

Here is some code:

> revisionEntity.java

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(AuditListener.class)
public class RevisionEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @RevisionNumber
    private int id;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    private long timestamp;

    private String username;
```

> LoginBean.java

```
@Named
@Stateful
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable{

private String username;
...
```

> AuditListener.java

```
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.hibernate.envers.RevisionListener;

import br.test.login.filterlogin.beans.LoginBean;

    @Named
    @Stateful
    @SessionScoped
    public class AuditListener implements RevisionListener {

        @Inject
        private LoginBean loginBean;

        public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {

            RevisionEntityEx RevEntity = (RevisionEntityEx) revisionEntity;
            RevEntity.setUsername(loginBean.getUsername());

        }
```

The loginBean injection fails, giving me a NullPointerException. Any ideas?

Sorry about my terrible grammar.

Regards,
Marcelo.

Answer (score 5):

The listener is not managed by the container so your *loginBean* will not be injected.

We need to lookup for it...

**Notice** that *UsuarioService* should be changed to your type: *LoginBean*.

```
import javax.enterprise.context.spi.CreationalContext;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI;

BeanManager beanManager = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
Bean<UsuarioService> bean = (Bean<UsuarioService>) beanManager.getBeans(UsuarioService.class).iterator().next();
CreationalContext<UsuarioService> context = beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean);
this.usuarioService = (UsuarioService) beanManager.getReference(bean, UsuarioService.class, context);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give any stacktrace, so I'm guessing. AFAIK you cannot combine together both

```
@Stateful
@SessionScoped
```

Because the first annotation is for making a class an EJB stateful session bean, but the second one is for making class a CDI managed bean, with scope `Session`.

It seems to me that you are trying to use technologies you don't understand at all. Please read a specification or at least some CDI tutorials/ sample GitHub projects.

**Personal advice**: most of the time you should prefer to use `@Stateless` over `@Stateful` for EJB beans. Then all data related to HTTP session you can store e.g. in some additional `@SessionScoped` CDI bean.